# BPMN2 timer events how to repeat after a delay?

Tags: camunda, bpmn

I am new to BPMN and camunda. How to implement this:
I have a user task, I want to set a timeout, let’s say 3 days.
If user don’t complete the task in 3 days, every hour I will send a SMS message to remind the user.
[image]
I tried to use boundary timer event to model the timeout, but failed to repeat the SMS notify task by 1 hour, as the intermedia timer catch event can only have duration, not cycle.
please help…

please note, the SMS task need to start after the 3 days timout.

I am using camunda desktop modeler 5.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the boundary timer event's timer expression can be:

```
"R3/" + substring(string(now() + duration("P3D")),1,19) + "Z/PT1H"
```

which means: start from 3 days later, repeat every 1 hour, max 3 times.

note: this may be camunda specific, may not apply to other bpmn implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this issue in that way (I say that because I'm also new to bpmn)

[image: Approve Process]

Let's have a closer look at the process chart

- the user should approve a task and he has three days to complete
- after three days of not completing the task an alternative path is opened (condition *Approval > 3 days*)
- now the first SMS is send as a reminder
- and we pass over to the approve task again (but in the alternative path)
- when the approval isn't done within one hour (condition *Wait 1 hour*)
- we go back with the link event to the task SMS notify

  - and that's a loop
- after some looping (condition *SMS > 10*) a second alternative path is opened to escalate this approval

  - also important for not having an endless loop

Comment: see my own answer, comment if you don't agree.